# PHP - Convert random colour generator to select from predefined colours

Tags: php, colors, web, generator

I'm using a tag cloud in joomla that uses a random colour generator to colour the text.

The code for this generator is as follows:

```
    foreach ($myTagss as $value){           
        // color
        switch ($color){
          case 'yes':
          // color
          mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
          $c = '';
          while((strlen($c)<6)){
            $c .= sprintf("%02X", mt_rand(0, 255));}
            $colorr = "color:#".$c."";
            // end color
          break;
          case 'no':
          $colorr = "";
          break;
     }
     // end color
```

The problem with this current setup is that the colours do not fit the webpage template and can often display a colour that is unreadable against the background.

I would like to change this code so that the colour is randomly selected from 6 predefined colours (or the colours are used in listed order) so that the text is clearly readable and fits in with the template.

Any advice that can be offered to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors[0] = "color:#FFFFFF"; 
etc..
```

Fill an array with strings of the colors, then use:

```
$key = mt_rand(0, 5);
```

to generate a random key for you, then simply request that key from your array.

```
$color = $colors[$key];
```